# Rails: error charting by time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating a chart based on account balance. And here is my some of my codes

```
module AccountsHelper
  def products_chart_data
    orders_by_day = Account.total_grouped_by_day(3.days.ago)
    (3.days.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
      {
        created_at: date,
        balance: orders_by_day[date].first.try(:total_balance) || 0 
      }
    end
  end
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :books

  def self.total_grouped_by_day(start)
    balances = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
    balances = balances.group("date(created_at)")
    balances = balances.select("created_at, balance as total_balance")
    balances.group_by {|o| o.created_at.to_date }
  end

end
```

My problems are:

1) I received an error undefined method `first' when mapping 3.days.ago, but successfully run the code when I change it to 2.days.ago. I understand that it is because I do not have data on 3 days ago as this account is new. My question is, how can I rescue this error, because I could have many other new accounts that do not have data yet, and what could I do to display result for 1 month, or 2 month?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#                            ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
balance: orders_by_day[date].try(:first).try(:total_balance) || 0
```

`try` is the method, introduced by rails and [defined on `Object` class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/44cff3045c5d98fb368e86949dd0973ee768c409/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L23-L24), therefore it is defined on `NilClass` as well.

The implementation is [quite straightforward](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/44cff3045c5d98fb368e86949dd0973ee768c409/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L5-L7): it checks whether receiver is empty and returns either the result of the call to it, or `nil` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I can use try on first/last. As balance is set to 0 for the days which do not have a record,  how can I write if I would like the balance be equal to the balance of previous day?

Comment: Please ask another question. SO rule is one problem per one question.